# Read child elements using C# from xml

Tags: c#, xml

Greeting,
What is the best practice to read all attributes from a child elements by ID attributes using C# in xml file listed down.

Thank you,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <WinDLN>

  <Program ID="1" Name="CIS562" StartDate="9/8/2010 5:50:00 PM" EndDate="9/8/2010 9:15:00 PM" />

  <Program ID="2" Name="CIS532" StartDate="10/8/2010 5:50:00 PM" EndDate="10/8/2010 9:15:00 PM" />

  <Program ID="3" Name="ECE552" StartDate="6/8/2010 5:50:00 PM" EndDate="6/8/2010 9:15:00 PM" />

</WinDLN>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following LINQ call should do the trick:

```
var attrs = 
  doc.Descendants("Program").First(prog =>
    prog.Attribute("ID").Value == "2").Attributes();
```

The `Descendants` method gives you all elements (anywhere) in the XML document that are named "Program". Using `First`, you can get the first one that matches some specified predicate (e.g. has "ID" equal to "2"). Note that you can use `FirstOrDefault` if you want to get `null` when there is no such element. Finally, `Attributes` gives you a collection of all attribtues of the element.

I think that using LINQ to XML if you can is preferrable - you'll write the same code when working with XML or other data sources, so reading and writing the code is easy (once you learn LINQ).

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do it, e.g. LINQ over XML. But using Xpath is definitely not dead yet:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string xml = @"... your xml ";
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        // Using SelectNodes with Xpath
        XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("WinDLN/Program[@ID='2']");
        Console.WriteLine(list.Count); // prints 1
        list = doc.SelectNodes("WinDLN/Program[@ID]");
        Console.WriteLine(list.Count); // prints 3 (selected all IDs)
    }
}
```

What method you'll choose is most often a matter of taste, select the API you're most comfortable with.