# how to get value of child nodes in xml one by one

Tags: c#, xml

How can i read asin and its value from This xml file.
i have multiple product in this xml file.
This two products asin i want to get.

```
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Product\WriteText2.xml");
        XElement match = xdoc.Root.Element("GetMatchingProductForIdResult");

        foreach(XElement product in match.Elements("Products"))
        {
            XElement asin = product.Element("Identifiers").Element("MarketplaceASIN").Element("ASIN");
            string asinValue = asin.Value;
        }
```

```html
      <GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="619659000431" IdType="UPC" status="Success">
            <Products>
              <Product>
                <Identifiers>
                  <MarketplaceASIN>
                    <MarketplaceId>A21TJRUUN4KGV</MarketplaceId>
                    <ASIN>B002U1ZBG0</ASIN>
                  </MarketplaceASIN>
                </Identifiers> 
                </Product>
        </Products>
      </GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
 <GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="190198462411" IdType="UPC" status="Success">
    <Products>
      <Product>
        <Identifiers>
          <MarketplaceASIN>
            <MarketplaceId>A21TJRUUN4KGV</MarketplaceId>
            <ASIN>B073Q5R6VR</ASIN>
          </MarketplaceASIN>
        </Identifiers>
</Product>
    </Products>
  </GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
```

Comment: What have you researched so far? Can you share?

Comment: Post a better sample of multiple objects.  One sample doesn't give me enough info to give a good answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read child elements using C# from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006916/read-child-elements-using-c-sharp-from-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Xml.Linq`:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
XElement match = xdoc.Element("GetMatchingProductForIdResult");

foreach(XElement product in match.Elements("Products")){
    XElement asin = product.Element("Identifiers")
        .Element("MarketplaceASIN").XElement("ASIN");
    string asinValue = asin.Value;
}
```

Comment: Worked for me.Thank you. :)